# Avoid automatically connecting to wireless network on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a internet connection with a Wi-Fi router. I use my Dell laptop to connect to it and it automatically connects to this network whenever it is available. This is just fine for me, However, sometimes one more wireless network becomes visible in my range and it seems my laptop tries to automatically connect to that network also. This causes a momentatry loss of network which is very irritating. Is there any where to configure windows not to try to connect to other networks than the one I use?

Answer (score 6):

You can open the Network and Sharing Center.  On the upper left, click "manage wireless networks".  right click the wireless network that is giving you trouble, and choose properties.  Uncheck the "Connect automatically when this network is in range".

Do you use a common SSID name, like "home" or "linksys"?  Wireless can be rather dumb.  We have a person that has a home network called "linksys".  when she is in the office, her computer sees a wireless network called "linksys" and connects.  However, that network is the building across the street, so she can't get to our network stuff.

We had her rename her how SSID to something much less likely to be duplicated, and that has fixed her problem.

Comment: Actually I see 2 networks (other than mine) in range. One is "linksys" :). When I open the manage wireless networks I see only my network listed there, hence unable to uncheck the "connect automatically..."

Comment: It should not connect automatically unless you have told it to do so for that particular SSID in the past. As long as your SSID is unique, your PC should not connect to any other address automatically unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an Intel Wireless Adapter? If so your wireless adapter has been set to connect to free hotspot automatically. To disable, open Intel PROSet/Wireless Tools (you can do that by searching it on your start menu), under "Intel Wifi Hotspot Assistant" click "Settings" and untick "Automatically Connect to Free Wifi hotspots"