# Disable Windows from automatically connect to a network when network is lost by option or setting the auto-connection option to off (by default)

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I work with different routers, I want my laptop to stop connecting to various wireless networks when a wireless connection is lost.
Is there a way to prevent my computer from doing this?

Bonus: If windows could only re-connect with the network it had before, that would be perfect.

---

Operating system: windows 7

Comment: Did you already turn off the auto-connect option on your saved WiFi networks?

Comment: It is possible to do that, but since I'm dealing with a lot of networks, isn't there a global option or register? Or set the auto-connection option to off by default?

Comment: Hey @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, how did you manage to close this as a dupe by yourself without being a mod?

Comment: @Karan It's due to my Gold badges earned for Windows and Windows-7 tags (in this case). More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/174452

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Thanks, wasn't visiting the site when this change was made so it took me by surprise. Congrats. :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows will only automatically connect to networks it remembers. It will not automatically connect to a public network either unless you set it to automatically connect.

So the only thing you can do is to forget that network and it will not connect to that network anymore.

Open your `network sharing center`, on the top left, click `adapters settings`. Open the `Wireless connection` and then there should be a tab with your logins that you can forget.

*I can't give you the exact names as I'm running Windows 8.1 and the names are not in English either, so I'm not 100% sure how to reach that place.*

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Network and Sharing Center. On the upper left, click "manage wireless networks". right click the wireless network that is giving you trouble, and choose properties. Uncheck the "Connect automatically when this network is in range".

Source [Avoid automatically connecting to wireless network on windows 7 - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/238181/avoid-automatically-connecting-to-wireless-network-on-windows-7?rq=1)

That is, configure the above setting for every Wi-Fi connection available in the system.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, this is the second answer of yours (there might be more) that seems to basically repeat what an earlier one said. It's nice that you credit the original solution, but if you come across a question that poses a fundamentally identical problem as an existing one, please vote to close the new one as a duplicate. (Or, if you lack the rep to vote then just leave a "Possible duplicate" comment with a link to the other question.)